# How to get value out of each block in handlebars

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js

I have following template:

```
<script id="basketTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}  
        <div>{{Title}}</div>               
        <div>{{Count}}</div>        
    {{/each}}
    <div>{{TotalCount}}</div>
</script>
```

In `each` block, everytinh is fine, but I could not get value for `TotalCount`,
How I can do this?

Edited:
I using following `JSON` object:

```
[{"ID":1,"Image":"no-pic.png","Count":2,"Title":"XXX","TotalCount":10},{"ID":2,"Image":"no-pic.png","Count":2,"Title":"XXX","TotalCount":10}, ...]
```

Now, please explain, what should I do, thanks :)

Please note:
I want to show `TotalCount` one time, so I can not put that into the iteration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` when used in the outmost scope of a Handlebars template refers to the entire object passed into the compiled template, in your case an array containing a lot of objects.

So for your exact problem you would have to register a helper, where you would have to fetch all sum from each object and then sum them up.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('sumTotalCount', function(list) {
  return list.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.TotalCount + b.TotalCount;
  });
});
```

and use it like this

```
{{#sumTotalCount this}}
    <div>{{output}}</div>
{{/sumTotalCount}}
```

Made a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/culuvicuse/1/) for you.

Comment: I can not do that man, because I want to show `TotalCount` one time.

Comment: I edited your solution to: `return list[0].TotalCount;` and that's work ! thanks :)